# Does Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 has records count limitations

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I've researched MSDN documentation for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 Requirements and Conditions and did not find any information about records count limitations.

How many records can I store in CRM entity lists and what're best practices about storing of large count of items (more than 1M records)?

I'm using CRM REST services to process some of data on the portal. So, how big size of target list can have influence on perfomance of select queries?

Comment: I found one article with description of migration process with total 40M records: http://www.altaisystems.com/TopNav/Blog/tabid/3129/ID/27/The-Great-Migration-40-Million-Records-Migrated-in-105-Hours.aspx They are using SSIS to import data from SQL Server via proxy class through CRM API services. Whole process have took about 10.5 hours. But I did not find any perfomance comments about select queries...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under CRM is MSSQL database so in most cases you can diagnose data performance problems with SQL tools ([Dynamic Management Views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188754.aspx) or [SQL Profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173799.aspx)) In company that I work for we have few entities with over 8M records and things are running smooth. We had to add a few indexes (without them some of our queries were running slow) also document [Optimizing and Maintaining a Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Server Infrastructure](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh413200(v=crm.6).aspx) was much help - even if it is for 2011 version many things are accurate for 2016.